# How do I protect the original source (URL) from being accessed directly BUT at the same time allow my iFrame to load that protected page?

Tags: iframe

I consider myself new to this, so I apologize if I am "off" in anyway.

I need to somehow get a HTML page to load in wordpress as if it was "part of the WP" page.

I have used an iFrame and this works fine (If there's a better solution I am all eyes).

The problem is that I need the HTML page to not be able to be accessed directly by the public. The iFrame however will load as normal.

How would this work? I am a beginner in PHP and somewhat know how .htaccess works. If I am given code please explain where to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some me to the page in your iframe, to detect that it is loaded in the frame and if not redirect to the parent page

```
if(window.self !== window.top) location.href = ‘http://...’
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add this to? Somewhere in the actual HTML file? I tried adding it before </head> and then before </body>. Neither worked. Does the parent and iFrame need to be on the same domain?

Comment: Inside a `<script>` tag in the head or body

Comment: This forced the iFrame to load the page "location.href = ‘http://...’" and left the parent page open to direct access by it's URL. I need the exact opposite.... parent page is redirected if NOT accessed in an iFrame and the iFrame is always showing the parent page.

Comment: ~The ultimate point is to restrict the parent pages content unless accessed through the url with the iFrame. I have the capability to make this work same-origin or different domain- either way that actually works is fine. I could be going about this all wrong to begin with, I admit.